# Display the minimum value based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula can be used to find the minimum value based on a criteria? Such as "Yes" or "No".

All help and guidance is appreciated.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/RakaBby.png]

Comment: Also check that `B2:B5` isn't blank? Or `=MINIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,"Yes")`.

Comment: or try entering the formuly with **ctrl** + **shift** + **enter**

Comment: `=MIN(IF((C2:C5="Yes")*(B2:B5<>""),B2:B5))` if your version of Excel doesn't support `MINIFS`.

Comment: @BigBen That's perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Excel supports `MINIFS`:

```
=MINIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,"Yes")
```

Otherwise:

```
=MIN(IF((C2:C5="Yes")*(B2:B5<>""),B2:B5))
```